# Unable to download Video from URL

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, urllib

I am trying to automatically download my online lectures with python (selenium, requests etc.). I was able to download the PDFs but when i tried to download the videos i stumbled upon the error:

```
HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

[This is the video I am trying to load](https://isis.tu-berlin.de/mod/videoservice/file.php/f1e282e0552e98b7fb0159896153709a56b1bea0b92a6eb7d21e7e2b1ca69972.mp4)

My current code goes like this:

```
def download_video(download_url, filename):
  req = urllib.request.Request(download_url, headers={
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
  })
  response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
  file = open(filename + ".pdf", 'wb')
  file.write(response.read())
  file.close()
```

Comment: You may need referrer header to be the site... or have authentication in the request.

Comment: @pcalkins I can download the video by rightclicking and selecting download so there must be a way to download this with python right?

Comment: Sure.  I would try adding the referrer header first.  That's the most common way to prevent "deep linking" methinks.  If that doesn't work, also add your user credentials (authentication) to your request.